# install libraspberrypi on top of arm32v7/python docker base image

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a small footprint docker image to run a python app that uses GPIO and camera. Everything works fine when using `FROM raspbian/stretch` as the base image in my Dockerfile.

If I understand correctly, I should be able to use the much smaller base images from https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/python/ but I'm having issues with performing `apt-get install libraspberrypi-bin` (in the Dockerfile)

I think I just need to add the following to sources.list:

`deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main`

but then I come up against GPG errors. So I've tried to `apt-get install gnupg` first, but now I get `Package 'gnupg' has no installation candidate`.

Maybe there is a different base image to use, or maybe the 'raspbian/stretch' base image is as small as it gets (but I doubt it)?